# weighted Laplacian

Tags: complex-analysis

My aim is to study a weighted Laplacian defined as
$$
L_1=\partial_z \left(\lvert z \rvert^{-2} \bar \partial_z\right), \quad z\in \mathbb{D}
$$
Here $\partial_z$ and $\bar \partial_z$ denote the two differential operators
$$
\partial_z=\frac{1}{2}\big 
(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\big ) \quad
\bar \partial_z=\frac{1}{2}\big 
(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\big ).
$$
And of particular interest is the equation

$$
L_1u=0 \quad \text{in} \quad \mathbb{D}
$$
and its associated Dirichlet boundary value problem
$$
\left\{
\begin{split}
L_1u=0 \quad \text{in} \quad \mathbb{D},\\
u=\varphi \quad \text{on} \quad \mathbb{T},
\end{split}
\right.
\normalsize
%\end{equation}
$$
How to deal with the singularity in the weight function?

Comment: I guess that if $u$ is proportional $|z|^m$ where $m$ is a positive enough integer, then it will cancel out $|z|^{-2}$ in the operator $L_1$.

Comment: Please explain, what do you mean with $u$ proportional to $\lvert z \rvert^m$?

Comment: for example $u=|z|^3 v$. so that function $v$ is well behaved at $x=y=0$. you then do not need to worry about the singularity explicitly in your subsequent treatment.

Comment: But what if $u$ is some other function?

Comment: if $u$ does not have a factor like $|z|^2$ or $|z|^3$ in it, then it will have singularity problem.

Comment: But if we can show that the the function is bounded for $z=0$ isn't the singularity removable according to Riemanns' theorem about removable singularities. Maybe I'm to confused in this. I was just interested in investigating the problem, but maybe it's more complicated than I thought.

Comment: You may set $x=r\cos\phi,y=r\sin\phi$ and convert $\partial_x,\partial_y$ to $\partial_r,\partial_\phi$ and then express $L_1$ in terms of $r,\phi$.  Now everything is in $r,\phi$. You will probably see how the singularity part in $L_1$, now becomes $r^{-2}$, affects the function $u(r,\phi)$.